# proving divergent sequence using epsilon definition

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove that a **sequence is divergent using epsilon definition** ?
Prove **an={log(1/n)}** diverges to **-infinity** by above definition.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say something like this: For every real number $L$, there exists an $\epsilon>0$, such that for every $N$ there exists some $n>N$ such that $|\log (1/n)-L|>\epsilon$. This will show that for every real number, $L$ is not the limit. Now to show it, you will have to make use of the fact that $\log(1/n)$ becomes arbitrarily negative as $n$ approaches infinity, and so no matter what $L$ is, you will always find some sufficiently large $n$ so that the absolute value of $|\log(1/n)|$ is so big, that it cannot be within a distance, of say, $\epsilon=1$ from the prescribed $L$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Taking any $M < 0$, we have $\log (n^{-1}) = -\log n < M$ if $n > e^{-M}$, so taking $N := \lceil e^{-M} \rceil$ suffices.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the epsilon definition here. Rather you want to show that given any number $R>0$ there exists a natural number, $ N$ such that for all $n>N$ $$log(1/n)<-R$$
which is equivalent to $$R<log(n)$$
It should be fairly easy now to see how to do it.